# jQuery scope of variables

Tags: javascript, jquery

I've got the following function:

```
function postToDrupal(contacts, source, owner) {
  (function ($) {
    $.post("/cloudsponge-post",function(contacts) {
      alert(contacts);
    });
  }(jQuery));
}
```

The problem I'm having is, contacts seems to be defined outside the jQuery closure, but not inside it. I'm a javascript newbie so this is confusing me. How can I get this to post contacts?

Comment: contacts is your data to sent to cloudsponge-post url? Am I right? If not can you elaborate little more.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You're masking the variable with a new variable with the same name when you re-use the name as the AJAX call's callback function parameter.

```
function postToDrupal(contacts, source, owner) {
  (function ($) {
    $.post("/cloudsponge-post",function(data) {  // <-- !!
      console.log(contacts);  // the first parameter of postToDrupal()
      console.log(data);      // the response from the AJAX call
    });
  }(jQuery));
}
```

Comment: OK, so to clarify, if I wanted to post 'contacts', I would need:
$.post("/cloudsponge-post",contacts,function(data) {

Answer (score 3):

You don't need to have `contacts` as a parameter again in your $.post() function.

If you do, you are making another variable local to $.post.

In javascript, variables are local to functions, not blocks.

I love this article: http://www.adequatelygood.com/JavaScript-Scoping-and-Hoisting.html

It's a very good read on understanding javascript scoping. Also there's something called "hoisting" you should know about.

Answer (score 0):

Try this one:

```
function postToDrupal(contacts, source, owner) {
  $.post("/cloudsponge-post",function(responseData) {
    alert(responseData);
    alert(contacts);
  });
}
```

Answer (score -1):

you can use this as syncronus ajax call. Rewriting the code and use it.

```
function postToDrupal(contacts, source, owner) {
var result = undefined;
    $.ajax( {
            type : 'GET',
            url : '/cloudsponge-post',
            async: false,
            success : function(contacts) {          
                result = contacts;
            }
        });
        return result;
}
```

Comment: a) Using async:false in this case is totally unnecessary and bad advice, and b) this doesn't fix the OP's problem (which is not being able to access the original `contacts` variable inside the success callback)